# Force Typo3 to evaluate DateTime as UTC

Tags: php, mysql, typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-11.x

We recently updated our installation from Typo3 v10.4.36 to v11.5.19. Since then Typo3 seems to be interpreting any datetime data saved in the DB as the servers timezone instead of UTC.

I have a column `start_date_time` of type `datetime`. All its values are saved in UTC time. In the past when reading data from that column Typo3 would correctly convert the values to the servers timezone - Europe/Berlin.

To illustrate further let's take two rows of my table. One has the value `2023-11-07 08:00:00`, the other the value `2023-08-22 07:00:00`.

Before the migration when debugging the object returned by the repository when querying for the first row the field had the value `2023-11-07T09:00:00+01:00`, with timestamp `1699344000`.
Further debugging the object representing the second row, the value was `2023-08-22T09:00:00+02:00` with timestamp `1692687600`, showing that Typo3 is capable of correcting for summer time.

However following the migration to v11 Typo3 seems to interpret the data from the database in the servers timezone. Now the same date is initialized as `2023-11-07T08:00:00+01:00`, timestamp `1699340400` and `2023-08-22T07:00:00+02:00`, timestamp `1692680400` respectively.

Is there a way to force Typo3 to interpret datetime values as UTC?

I tried

- manually setting the timezone of the server in `php.ini`, tried both `UTC` and `Europe/Berlin`
- manually setting `[SYS][phpTimeZone]`, tried both `UTC` and `Europe/Berlin`
- setting `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['AdditionalConfiguration']['tx_myextension_mytable']['initCommands'] = [SET time_zone = "+00:00"'];` in `AdditionalConfiguration.php`
- verify that nothing changed in the timezone settings of my database

Comment: Did you crosscheck the PHP Timezone in your phpinfo() ? Maybe you changed the php.ini for the cli version of php.

Comment: yup, I verified that by checking PHPInfo in the Environment tab of Typo3. Right now I have one instance running on Europe/Berlin and one instance on Australia/Sydney but all datetime objects across both instances are of timezone Europe/Berlin.

Comment: This seems to be known, unfixed bug for years now https://forge.typo3.org/issues/68651